# Can GCP VM's run while I am offline?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Can GCP VM's run while I am offline? I am using a GCP Deeplearning notebook VM with GPU to train a neural network. When I close the Jupyter notebook tab, **the code stops executing** while the instance is still alive and I get billed. Is there a way to run the code while I am offline? I think this must be possible.

Comment: if you can convert it to a python script, then it can be done with full certainity using `nohup script.py &` command.

Comment: Yes of course, you can use `nohup python.py &` to run the script in the background. [nohup](https://janakiev.com/blog/python-background/)

Comment: Notebook instance are designed for experimentation. Ifyou want to run a training, you have training environment dedicated to this.

Comment: Thank you everybody for your comments, I am looking for using `nohup`.

Comment: Hey guys, can you add this as an answer, so that the community members find the answer to the question?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everybody who commented on this question.

You can run python scripts in GCP Deeplearning notebook VM in the background through `nohup`.

```
!nohup python train.py --epochs=10 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

you can save as executable script your code, then enter to the vm through SSH console, and then use the following command

`nohup python code.py > out.log &`

this will make run your script and you can close ssh window if you want.

if you want to check the execution status just execute cat or tail command over the file out.log :)